# Update Multiple rows when matching multiple rows in another table

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a store table that have more rows in it with a column named Quantity, i have tempStore table also, i insert Data to this tempStore table and it has a column named Quantity as well, when i enter all my data in to tempStore then i have a Send button to send my data to Store table to update only the Quantity column, for example in Store table Quantity=20 for one row, and in tempStore Quantity=10 for one row, i can easily update this row when i press send button, the Quantity column in Store table will be 30, but why i can't update all rows that match?it does it only for one row.
this is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = null;
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SuperMarketDB;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Store]", con);
SqlDataReader dr = null;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int inID = 0;
Int64 itemNo = 0;
int iQuantity = 0;

while (dr.Read())
{
    inID = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
    itemNo = Int64.Parse(dr[1].ToString());
    iQuantity = int.Parse(dr[4].ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i <= tempStoreDataGridView.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        if (tempStoreDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            Int64 barcode = Int64.Parse(tempStoreDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            if (barcode == itemNo)
            {                   
                iQuantity = iQuantity + int.Parse(quantityTextBox.Text.ToString());
                inItemsTableAdapter1.UpdateQuery(iQuantity, itemNo, inID);
                tempStoreTableAdapter.DeleteQuery();
                tempStoreTableAdapter.Fill(this.tempStoreDataSet.TempStore);
                lblWarning.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You perform excess operations: first a data in target type you convert to string, then back to target type. Use [`SqlDataReader.GetIn64(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint64.aspx) and similar.

Comment: ur comment is not clear, please clarify.

Comment: Instead of `int i = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());` use `int i = dr.GetInt32(0);`, that much more effective.

Comment: OK, i did but this is not my problem, read my question.

Comment: I know, that's just a offtopic and background suggestion, that's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comment, appreciation.